# References for this theorem of Pfister?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, reference-request

Here is the statement from Pfister :

> Let $K$ a field (s.t : char$(K)\neq 2$). Let $a_1,\dots a_n \in \mathbb{K}^{\times}$, $P\in K[X]$, $F_1,\dots,F_n \in K(X)$ s.t : $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_jF_j^2=P$. Then there exists $P_1,\dots,P_n \in K[X]$ s.t : $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_jP_j^2=P$.

I was wondering if someone had references or some literature for this statement ?

I think that this result could be generalized to several indeterminate (for $K(X_1,\dots,X_k)$).

Also, are there improvements and generalizations of this result (I was thinking about optimization's problems with "positive" polynomials and sums of squares in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$) ? What happen if $K$ is no more a field (for instance $\mathbb{Z}$) ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Theorem 3.1 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/sumsquareQF(T).pdf

Comment: I doubt there is an analogue with positive-coefficient polynomials. The polynomial $x^4 - x^2y^2 + y^4$ can be written as $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$ with $a = \dfrac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}$, $b = \dfrac{y^4}{x^2+y^2}$, $c = \dfrac{x^3y}{x^2+y^2}$ and $d = \dfrac{xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$, but clearly cannot be written as a sum of squares of polynomials with nonnegative coefficients.

Comment: @darijgrinberg thank you for this interesting document !

Comment: @darijgrinberg you are right ! It was for "sos" polynomials